# Inverse Trigonometric functions involving square roots

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following question:

$$ cot^{-1}\dfrac{  \sqrt { 1 + \sin x }  -  \sqrt { 1 - \sin x } }{ \sqrt { 1 + \sin x +  \sqrt { 1 - \sin x }}} $$

At first I tried converting it to:

$$ tan^{-1}\dfrac{  \sqrt { 1 + \sin x }  +  \sqrt { 1 - \sin x } }{ \sqrt { 1 + \sin x-  \sqrt { 1 - \sin x }}} $$

then multiply and divide numerator by $  \sqrt { 1 + \sin x }$ gives me

$$ tan^{-1}\dfrac{  ( 1 + \sin x)  +  \cos x  }{ ( 1 + \sin x)  - \sqrt{cos x}  } $$

I need to prove the above to be x/2. But have no idea what to do next, looking forward 
to your help. :)

Comment: Please clarify your denominator! As shown in my answer (and by Claude) the original formula will **not** reduce to $x/2$. After the edit from @Narasimham the situation is even more confusing.

Comment: @gammatester sorry , edited my question

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}$
We have the identities:
$$ 1+\sin{x} = \sin{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi} + \sin{x} = 2\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)} \cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x-\pi}{2}\right)} = 2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right), $$
and similarly
$$ 1-\sin{x} = 2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right) = 2\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right). $$
Now, taking the positive square roots reduces your fraction in the $\arccot$ to
$$ \frac{\sqrt{2}\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}-\sqrt{2}\cos{\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}}{\sqrt{2}\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}+\sqrt{2}\cos{\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}} $$
Next, expanding the sines and cosines gives
$$ \frac{\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}+\cos{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}-\cos{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}}{\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}+\cos{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}+\cos{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}} = \frac{\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}{\cos{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}} = \tan{\tfrac{1}{2}x} $$
Hence the formula you give is wrong: it should be
$$ \arccot{\tan{\tfrac{1}{2}x}} = \frac{\pi-x}{2}, $$
for $0<x<\pi/2$, at least: other intervals you can work out yourself using different signs for the square roots.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Start simplifying the argument to get $$A=\frac{\sqrt{1+a}+\sqrt{1-a}}{\sqrt{1+a}-\sqrt{1-a}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}$$ Replace $a=\sin(x)$ which gives $$A=\frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$ Now, use the half angle $t=\tan(\frac x2)$ which makes $$A=\frac 1t$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

**Edit**

The denominator I used was wrong. The result cannot be $\frac x2$ since, built at $x=0$, Taylor series of the argument is $$ \frac{\sqrt{1+\sin x}+\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1+\sin x-\sqrt{1-\sin x}}}=\frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{6
   \sqrt{6}}+O\left(x^{3/2}\right)$$

Comment: Please read my question , i think you have mis-interpreted the denominator , thx for the attempt :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a slightly wrong formula
$$f : x \longrightarrow \cot^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin x}+\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1+\sin x-\sqrt{1-\sin x}}}\right)$$
instead of 
$$g : x \longrightarrow \cot^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin x}+\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1+\sin x}-\sqrt{1-\sin x}}\right)$$
Plugging in some values you get
$f(1)\approx 0.600236, \; f(1.5)\approx 0.761663$ and 
$g(1)=0.5, \; g(1.5)=0.75$